# How to get an int value using QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod?

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface, qtandroidextras

I know that using the following method, I could get a string from the Android main activity to Qt/C++ side.

```
QAndroidJniObject my_string = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod<jstring>("someMethod");
QString  my_qsrting = my_string.toString();
```

Above is great if `someMethod` returns a Java `String`. But what if `someMethod` returns an int? Following way does not work in Qt? It has compilation errors.

```
QAndroidJniObject my_int = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod<jint>("someMethod");
```

How can I collect an `int` or a `jint` using `QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod`?

Going through [this link](http://schorsch.efi.fh-nuernberg.de/roettger/index.php/QtOnAndroid/JNI), I could not find the answer to my question.

**Qt version:**
Qt 5.12 commercial version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `callObjectMethod` for methods that return primitives; you use [`callMethod`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#callMethod) for that:

```
jint my_int = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callMethod<jint>("someMethod");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thats what I needed :D